# Verify openssl rsa/pss signature with Java

Tags: java, openssl, rsa

I have this instruction for signature verification using OpenSSL

```
cat file_1 file_2 > data.bin
openssl dgst -sha1 -binary data.bin > data.bin.digest
openssl pkeyutl -verify -in data.bin.digest -inkey public.key -sigfile file.sign -pubin -pkeyopt rsa_padding_mode:pss -pkeyopt digest:sha1 -pkeyopt rsa_mgf1_md:sha1
```

I need to realize this instruction with Java.

For now, I'm trying to realize only the last command, which is doing the actual verification, like this:

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
//public key
FileInputStream keyfis = new FileInputStream(keyPath);
byte[] encKey = new byte[keyfis.available()];
keyfis.read(encKey);
keyfis.close();
X509EncodedKeySpec pubKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(encKey);
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PublicKey pubKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);
//sign file
FileInputStream sigfis = new FileInputStream(signPath);
byte[] sigToVerify = new byte[sigfis.available()]; 
sigfis.read(sigToVerify);
sigfis.close();
//verification
sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA/PSS");
sig.setParameter(new PSSParameterSpec("SHA-1", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA1, 32, 1));
sig.initVerify(pubKey);
byte[] dgst = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File("C:\\tmp\\data.bin.digest"));
boolean verifies = sig.verify(dgst);
System.out.println("signature verifies: " + verifies);
```

with OpenSSL I get "Signature Verified Successfully", but Java returns "signature verified: false"

What am I missing in Java code?

UPDATE

The corrected code will be

```
//verification
sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA/PSS");
sig.setParameter(new PSSParameterSpec("SHA-1", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA1, 234, 1));
sig.initVerify(pubKey);
byte[] file = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File("C:\\tmp\\data.bin"));
sig.update(file, 0, file.length);
boolean verifies = sig.verify(sigToVerify);
System.out.println("signature verified: " + verifies);
```

Comment: In the Java code the data is hashed _implicitly_, i.e. you must not pass the hash, but the original data (_data.bin_). Also, the data is not passed in `verify()`, but in `update()`. In `verify()` the signature is passed. The salt size is probably not 32 bytes either. Usually it corresponds to the digest output size, i.e. 20 bytes for SHA1. OpenSSL may use the maximum allowed salt size: `signature size - digest output size - 2 = 256 - 20 - 2` (in my repro this was the case). You have to test this out.

Comment: @Topaco Yes, that helped! Thank you!